# Best way to share Android app with Azure

Tags: android, azure, azure-web-app-service

We have a website hosted as an Azure web app service. The system also has an Android client. The system is a LOB system with known customers and (at the moment) we don't want to host the app in Google Play at the moment.

At the moment we share the Android apk through the website but that always requires a new build of the web even when only the android app has changed.

Problem with just republishing the app service are twofold:

1. The site is an Asp.net Core site with WebJobs. At the moment tooling doesn't support deploying WebJobs with Asp.net Core sites so with every build we have to reupload the WebJob through the Azure portal so we don't want to increase the amount of builds.
2. The apk needs to be added to the visual studio project and the removed after deployment so we don't add the apk to version control.

Provisioning a CDN service just for this apk file is overkill. Hosting it in Azure blob storage is an option but don't know how to manually update a row there.

Requirements are that the url the the apk file should be static, either so that the Azure resource would have a static url or that the web site could stream the file from some Azure storage.

Are there any better ways to host an app in Azure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If someones interested I ended up creating a Storage account for blobs and it turned out I could upload and edit the blobs directly from Visual Studio. The apk then got the url
https://storageaccount.blob.core.windows.net/mycontainer/myapp.apk